# The correct way of using UnitOfWork in Repository Pattern

Tags: asp.net, repository, unit-of-work

I'm trying to follow a tutorial on using the unit of work and repository pattern on MSDN but I've stumbled at the below:

```
private UnitOfWork unitOfWork = new UnitOfWork();
```

"This code adds a class variable for the UnitOfWork class. (If you were using interfaces here, you wouldn't initialize the variable here; instead, you'd implement a pattern of two constructors"

Basically, I need to call my UnitOfWork class in my LogController without actually using the above code as I'm using an interface? How is this possible? I'm not sure what it means by 'two constructors'.

Any advice would be appreiciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your class you define

```
Private IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork = null;
```

And you have one constructor which accepts an IUnitOfWork so the caller can pass in an implementation:

```
Public MyClass (IUnitOfWork unitOfWork) {
  _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
}
```

And you have another which does not, but knows how to go and find which implementation to create. Either it can use a default implementation, or it can go to some config file you've written to define which type to use, etc.

Within the MyClass you still call _unitOfWork.whateverMethod()